# Java script not submitting Html form

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am using following javascript to submit the form but it's not submitting.

```
 if(timeup)
        {
         alert("welcome to time up.");
        var id = document.getElementById("test_id").value;
        var no = document.getElementById("noq").value;
      var action = 'result.php?id='+id+'&no='+no+'';

    exercisenew.action = action;
    alert("form"+exercisenew.action);
   exercisenew.submit();
       alert("form submitted.");
    }
```

full code [here](http://pastie.org/6148393).

Html form.

```
<form method="post" action="" id="exercisenew" name="exercisenew">
```

Comment: where you defined exercisenew?

Comment: You have nothing in your action of your form, where it will get submitted ?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(timeup)
{
  alert("welcome to time up.");
  var id = document.getElementById("test_id").value;
  var no = document.getElementById("noq").value;

  //use encodeURIComponent()
  var action = encodeURIComponent('result.php?id='+id+'&no='+no+'');

  //get the form
  var exercisenew = document.getElementById("exercisenew")
  exercisenew.action = action;

  alert("form"+exercisenew.action);
  exercisenew.submit();
  alert("form submitted.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create object for `exercisenew`

```
var exercisenew = document.getElementById("exercisenew")
```

and do all the stuffs you have done